# Change state attributes to a group of widgets in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a checkbutton which is associated to a group of other widgets. What I would like to do is when the checkbutton is checked I want to change all the the associated/child widgets state from disabled to active.

I was thinking to change the state of my associated widgets from a callback function but I don't want to configure each widget individually.  Is there a way to group all the child widgets together so I can change all child widgets state all at once instead of configuring individually?

```
checkbutton 1 (unchecked)
    entry1 (disable)
    entry2 (disable)
    ...
    entry20 (disable)

checkbutton is checked

checkbutton 1 (checked)
    entry1 (active)
    entry2 (active)
    ...
    entry20 (active
```

I am sure there has to be a way to group them so I don't have to configure each 20 widgets properties individually. this will be helpful so I can create dictionaries of my settings and then I can change large amount of widgets by changing my dictionary.

Comment: you must configure each one individually. All you have to do is keep a list of all of the widgets, and iterate over the list. It takes two lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve your problem by designing your program as follows:

- Hold  each `Checkbutton` with its associated  group of other widgets inside one single widget (`Frame` or `Label` would be more appropriate)
- To use a `Checkbutton`, you must create a Tkinter variable. To inspect the button state, query the variable ([source](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)).
- If the variable above is changed, loop over the widgets associated to the `Checkbutton` in question and change their state.

The last point is done this way ([more info](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html)):

```
for associated_widget in frame.winfo_children():
    associated_widget.configure(state='disabled')
```

This approach will save you a lot of headaches.

## Code

Here is a simple MCVE demonstrating the feasibility of this approach:

```
'''
Created on Jun 19, 2016

@author: Billal Begueradj
'''
import Tkinter as Tk

class Begueradj(Tk.Frame):
   '''
   Control the state of multiple widgets associated to a checkbutton
   '''
   def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Inititialize the GUI with a button and a Canvas objects
        '''
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

   def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """
        Draw the GUI
        """
        self.parent.title("Billal BEGUERADJ")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")    
        # Draw a frame 
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent, bg='yellow')
        self.frame.pack(side='left')

        self.var = Tk.IntVar()  
        # Draw a checkbutton  on the frame
        self.checkbutton = Tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text="Group 1", variable=self.var, command=self.callback1)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Draw  5 buttons on the frame
        for i in range(5):
            self.button = Tk.Button(self.frame, text ='Button '+str(i))
            self.button.grid(row=i+1, column=0)

        #  Draw a Label 
        self.label = Tk.Label(self.parent, bg='blue')
        self.label.pack(side='right')
        #  Draw a checkbutton  on the label
        self.v = Tk.IntVar()  
        self.checkbuton = Tk.Checkbutton(self.label, text="Group 2", variable=self.v, command=self.callback2)
        self.checkbuton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Draw 5 buttons  on the label
        for i in range(5):
            self.button = Tk.Button(self.label, text ='Button '+str(i))
            self.button.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
        print self.checkbutton
   # Callback for checkbutton
   def callback1(self):
      if self.var.get() == 1:
         for w in self.frame.winfo_children():
           w.configure(state='disabled')

      self.checkbutton.configure(state='normal')

   # Callback for checkbuton
   def callback2(self):
      if self.v.get() == 1:
         for w in self.label.winfo_children():
           w.configure(state='disabled')

      self.checkbuton.configure(state='normal')





# Main method
def main():
    root=Tk.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running above program after checking the `Checkbutton` of the the first group:

[image]